# Connect to MySQL in Ruby using NetBeans

Tags: mysql, ruby, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I've downloaded the `dbd-mysql-0.4.4.zip` and linked it to my project. While I try to run a demo code from NetBeans the very first line (shown below) gives me an error. Is there a different way to do it?

```
require "dbi";
```

I also tried this command from the command prompt:

```
jruby setup.rb config --with=dbi,dbd_mysql
```

It gave me the following error:

```
config: unknown option --with=dbi,dbd_mysql  
Try ruby setup.rb --help for detailed usage.
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with jruby, you need to use `dbd-jdbc`, because `dbd-mysql` depends on `mysql` a native extension (written in C) for Matz' Ruby interpreter.

Install it using rubygems: `jruby -S gem install dbi`, and add `require 'rubygems'` as the first line of your code.